# Can I use "expect/actual const val"?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to make some multiplatform function, with default argument value provided by the platform(JVM, JS, ...).

I tried to put `const` keyword into expect/actual value, but compiler complained.

- Common part:

```
expect const val PLATFORM: String
expect fun printPlatform(value: String = PLATFORM)
```

- Actual part(in jvm):

```
actual const val PLATFORM: String = "JVM"
actual fun printPlatform(value: String) {
    System.out.println("Platform: $value")
}
```

But compiler complains: `Const 'val' should have an initializer.`
And if I remove `const` keyword from both of them, the performance may be lower than before(actually not significant but..) and compiler suggests: `Might be 'const'`. So I want to use `const` keyword.
Also, If I put default value in actual part, compiler also complains.

Can't I use `const val` in expect/actual pattern?

EDIT: I'm only using JVM actual in fact, but I use kotlin mpp as I might have to support other platforms.

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about performance.  I suspect the JVM is very likely to inline getting a final variable, so even if this value is critical, you probably won't see any difference.  (I don't know about JS or native, but even if they don't inline, it would take a pretty rare program to make the difference noticeable.)

Comment: @gidds Yes, I knew that there would be actually almost no difference, but I'm just wondering is there any ways to inline expect/actual value. `expect class`, `expect fun`, `expect val`, `expect var`, why not `expect const val`? In addition, compiler warns about not putting `const` into it. (can be ignored, but unconfortable for me; how to suppress it?)

Comment: I also think that this might be a bug and can be fixed with few lines of code.